# Error when trying to connect discovery-server to config-server using docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

I have created Discovery Server and Config Server microservices and I am trying to get the Discovery Server properties that are in Config.

I'm trying to dockerize these two services and for that I created a docker-compose.yml, but when I run the containers Eureka Server is throwing a "Connection refused" exception. The configuration server is starting normally, but the eureka server is throwing an exception.

When I run both services through the IDE they work normally, but not through docker-compose.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

**application.yaml (config-server)**

```
server:
  port: 8888
  
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/GustavoSC1/Event-Management-Config-Files-Test
          default-label: main
          search-paths:
          - 'config*'
```

**application.yaml (discovery-server)**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-server
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888
```

**Dockerfile example**

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=discovery-server/target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:   
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.12.0-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ../dados:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
    networks:
      - microservices-network
      
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:3.0.6
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - 9411:9411
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://user:password@rabbitmq:5672
    networks:
      - microservices-network

config-server:
    image: gustavosc1/config-server
    container_name: config-server
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config-server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    networks:
      - microservices-network
      
  discovery-server:
    image: gustavosc1/discovery-server
    container_name: discovery-server
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: discovery-server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    environment:
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin:9411/
      MANAGEMENT.ZIPKIN.TRACING.ENDPOINT: http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://user:password@rabbitmq:5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit
    depends_on:
      config-server:
        condition: service_started
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - microservices-network

networks:
  microservices-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**naming-server Logs**

```
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.042Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.g.d.DiscoveryServerApplication: Starting DiscoveryServerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.2 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2024-03-19T21:18:19.047Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.g.d.DiscoveryServerApplication: 
No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.233Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Fetching config from server at : http://config-server:8888
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.234Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Exception on Url - http://config-server:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/discovery-server/default": Connection refused. Will be trying the next url if available
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.234Z  WARN 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@6f1de4c7 uris = array<String>['http://config-server:8888'], optional = true, profiles = 'default']): I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/discovery-server/default": Connection refused
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.234Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Fetching config from server at : http://config-server:8888
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.234Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Exception on Url - http://config-server:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/discovery-server/default": Connection refused. Will be trying the next url if available
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.235Z  WARN 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@55182842 uris = array<String>['http://config-server:8888'], optional = true, profiles = 'default']): I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/discovery-server/default": Connection refused
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.235Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Fetching config from server at : http://config-server:8888
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.235Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Exception on Url - http://config-server:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/discovery-server/default": Connection refused. Will be trying the next url if available
    2024-03-19T21:18:19.235Z  WARN 1 --- [main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader: 
Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@3270d194 uris = array<String>['http://config-server:8888'], optional = true, profiles = 'default']): I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/discovery-server/default": Connection refused
    2024-03-19T21:18:24.408Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope: BeanFactory id=6b5919a6-3e46-31f6-a94c-c0261c3e21bc
    2024-03-19T21:18:25.183Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2024-03-19T21:18:25.225Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService: Starting service [Tomcat]
    2024-03-19T21:18:25.225Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.17]
    2024-03-19T21:18:25.606Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2024-03-19T21:18:25.609Z  INFO 1 --- [main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6367 ms
    2024-03-19T21:18:32.739Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2024-03-19T21:18:32.743Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2024-03-19T21:18:33.598Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
    2024-03-19T21:18:33.599Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.009Z  WARN 1 --- [main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger: Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.097Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory: Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.373Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.474Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.474Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.474Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.474Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider: Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.786Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver: Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.874Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Disable delta property : false
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.874Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Single vip registry refresh property : null
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.875Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Force full registry fetch : false
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.875Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Application is null : false
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.875Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Registered Applications size is zero : true
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.876Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Application version is -1: true
    2024-03-19T21:18:36.876Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
    2024-03-19T21:18:37.192Z  INFO 1 --- [main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
stacktrace=jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:270)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:300)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:662)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:661)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:413)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:313)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey3.AbstractJersey3EurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJersey3EurekaHttpClient.java:266)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey3.AbstractJersey3EurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJersey3EurekaHttpClient.java:213)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1045)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:958)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:396)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:247)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:242)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:68)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:320)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:558)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:364)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:361)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:224)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy74.getApplications(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.peerAwareInstanceRegistry(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:211)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:558)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:558)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:773)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:756)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:746)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1310)
        at com.gustavo.discoveryserver.DiscoveryServerApplication.main(DiscoveryServerApplication.java:12)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
        at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:423)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:268)
        ... 115 more

2024-03-19T21:18:37.192Z  WARN 1 --- [main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient: Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2024-03-19T21:18:37.194Z  INFO 1 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: DiscoveryClient_DISCOVERY-SERVER/245b579f1c93:discovery-server - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```